# Stop Group Test if Assertion Failed in NightwatchJS

Tags: testing, nightwatch.js

Is there a way to stop test execution if assertion failed so other test group will not be executed ?

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#assertions):

```
Nightwatch.js instance has two objects containing the same methods to perform
assertions on elements:

  .assert - when an assertion fails, the test ends, skipping all other assertions.
  .verify - when an assertion fails, the test logs the failure and continues with
            other assertions.
```

So I guess use `assert`? Unless you are and that's not working for you?

Answer (score 2):

Using assert will stop the current test, but to stop the whole suite, you need to set the setting 'skip_testcases_on_fail' to true in your nightwatch.json config file.